# Feature engineering for hierarchical data

Tags: feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I am working on the KDD dataset given in this [link](https://www.kaggle.com/c/kddcup2012-track1#Description).

The dataset is related to a typical recommendation systems dataset. So you find an item and information about the item. One of the information given about the Item is its category. Item-Category is a string `a.b.c.d`, where the character delimits the categories in the hierarchy `.`, ordered in a top-down fashion (i.e., category `a` is a parent category of `b`, and category `b` is a parent category of `c`, and so on.

I'm not sure how to use this information correctly in my feature engineering. For example, the simplest information I can derive is for each Item I can estimate the topmost category to which it belongs. However, to go beyond this and use the subcategory information, how can I model this feature for a linear regression?